# Vue js : Error in created hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined"

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am getting mentioned error with my learning app which am writing  as well as this error `Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getters' of undefined"` as well,  my codes are as below

I made sure everthing is imported correctly but still getting this error , am I missing something here?

**Main.js**

```
   import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import { routes } from './routes.js';
import { store } from './store/store.js';

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes,
  mode: 'history'
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
});
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <app-Header></app-Header>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Header from "./components/Header.vue";
import store from "./store/store.js";
export default {
  created() {
    this.$store.dispatch("initStocks");
  },
  components: {
    appHeader: Header
  }
};
</script>

<style></style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to correct this from `import { store } from './store/store.js';` to `import store from './store/store.js';`